# Android Ringtone Picker Activity crashing on select devices....specifically Nexus S

Tags: android, android-activity, ringtone

I have the following code in my app to allow the user to select a specific ringtone which will be played when *my app* notifies the user (I'm not trying to change the default ringer on the device):

```
public void ringtonePicker() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

    return;
    }

    if (requestCode == 999) {

        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        if (uri != null) 
        {

            String ringTonePath = uri.toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit(); //opens shared preference editor
            editor.putString("storedRingtoneLocation", ringTonePath);
            editor.commit();


            populateList(settingsList, settingsListDetails = getAndSetDetails(settingsList.length));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Ringtone Path Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Code is Bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

This is working on my test device (I only have one....HTC Evo) and in my emulators running 2.2 and 2.3.

I know for fact that this will cause a force-close on the Nexus S as my users have reported.  I do not know the model names of other devices with which this code experiences issues.  Any ideas?  The stack trace from the developer console shows this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity.onPrepareListView(RingtonePickerActivity.java:214)
>   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:905)
>   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:824)
>   at com.android.internal.app.AlertActivity.setupAlert(AlertActivity.java:73)
>   at com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity.onCreate(RingtonePickerActivity.java:188)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   ... 11 more

Specifically, you can see a nullPointerException at RingtonePickerActivity.java:214.  After inspect [RingtonePickerActivity.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/app/RingtonePickerActivity.java) at grepcode and looking at class, one can see at line 214 that the class is looking for the integer *addDefaultRintoneItem*.

I don't know of anyone with a Nexus S could test this out, but I was thinking that removing the line
`intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true`
from my code might correct the nullPointer.

Can anyone validate my theory?  Has no one else experienced this issue?  I've only found one thread on SO pertaining to this issue and it seems the thread activity died before an answer was derived.  Has no one else experienced this or am I just doing this the wrong way?

Comment: I get a similar error from select users/devices: 

 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.RingtonePickerActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _data: , while compiling: SELECT _data FROM system WHERE (name=?)

 - As far as I can tell, this is a bug in Android and should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ringtone picker does not exist sometimes for whatever reason. You've gotten a null pointer, just wrap it in a try cache and show a dialog saying the ringtone picker doesn't exist.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm still a noob, but if I'm getting a nullpointer @ line 214 in RingtonePickerActivity.java, doesn't that mean that the Ringtone picker exists?